# Python : Count frequences in dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary, counter

i want to count the number of each value in a dictionary, and construct a new one with the value as the key, and a list of keys that had said value as the value.

```
Input :
b = {'a':3,'b':3,'c':8,'d':3,'e':8}
Output:
c = { '3':[a. b. d]
      '8':[c, e]
                    }
```

I ve written the following, but it raises a key error and doesnt give any output, could someone help?

```
def dictfreq(b):
    counter = dict()
    for k,v in b.iteritems():
        if v not in counter:
            counter[v].append(k)
        else:
            counter[v].append(k)

    return counter


print dictfreq(b)
```

Comment: `if v not in counter:` - if there is no `v` in counter dict, why are you asking for it just line below? `counter[v].append(something)`?

Comment: I know you want to implement this yourself, but just for the record: there is a built-in Counter in the `itertools` module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
    if v not in counter:
        counter[v].append(k)
    else:
        counter[v].append(k)
```

to this:

```
    if v not in counter:
        counter[v] = []   # add empty `list` if value `v` is not found as key
    counter[v].append(k)
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. Is this the general way i can avoid key errors? Just declare an empty string/list/whathaveyou in place?

Comment: @onlyf Indeed, it is. Other solutions like `defaultdict` do exactly that under the hood.

Comment: Alright, thank you! This has been a reoccuring headache to a new guy like me.

Answer (score 5):

Better way to achieve this is via using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). For example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
b = {'a':3,'b':3,'c':8,'d':3,'e':8}

new_dict = defaultdict(list)  # `list` as default value
for k, v in b.items():
    new_dict[v].append(k)
```

The final value hold by `new_dict` will be:

```
{8: ['c', 'e'], 3: ['a', 'b', 'd']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict.setdefault` method:

```
>>> c =  {}
>>> for key, value in b.iteritems():
...     c.setdefault(value, []).append(key)
...
>>> c
{8: ['c', 'e'], 3: ['a', 'b', 'd']}
```

In Python3 use `b.items()` instead.